# SharePoint Migration tool mover.io - does it migrate content between SPOnline

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, migration, limitations, sharepointmigrationtool

I was looking into this SharePoint Migration Tool from MS. But I don't know how to get it to migrate content between 2 SP online content.

I installed it from [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointmigration/introducing-the-sharepoint-migration-tool).

When I try to add SP Online URL as a source it tells me it wants only on-premises site.

Can I do SP Online to SP Online?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to **migration from between Microsoft 365 tenants**, then we recommend you to use the Mover migration tool.

**The Mover tool is ideal for:**

- Microsoft 365 tenant to tenant migration
- Egnyte
- Amazon S3
- Azure Blob Storage
- Google Cloud Storage

**Here are a few articles that may be helpful to you:**

- [Migrate your content to Microsoft 365](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointmigration/migrate-to-sharepoint-online#other-migrations)
- [Mover Cloud Migration](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointmigration/mover-plan-migration)

=========================== **Update Answer** ========================

SPMT and Mover are two different migration products

Mover is exclusively for migrating data to Microsoft 365.

**Supported destinations:**

- OneDrive
- OneDrive for Business
- SharePoint Online sites
- Teams sites
- Azure Blob Storage

[image]

For more information, please click **[this link](https://mover.io/index.html)**.

Comment: Thanks EchoDU_MSFT for the reply.
Is this not the same tool i had in my OP?
I just dont see the options to migrate content between 2 SharePoint Online
Is this possible?

Comment: Hi naijacoder. Thanks for your reply. I have updated answer under initial My Answer. Hope this can help you to solve issue. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

New SPMT only supports migration from:

- SharePoint Server 2010, 2013, and 2016
- SharePoint Foundation 2010 and 2013
- File shares

You can find more information in below articles:

1. [Overview of the SharePoint Migration Tool (SPMT)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointmigration/introducing-the-sharepoint-migration-tool)
2. [SPMT-supported features](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointmigration/what-is-supported-spmt)

Comment: Thanks Ganesh for your reply.
So what i understand is this tool can't do what I want which means move content between SP Online?

Comment: Yes, new SPMT is not supported for migration between two SP online tenants.